# Django Multiple Choice Form with Parent Categories

Tags: python, django, forms, parent-child, multiple-choice

I have a simple model that looks like this:

```
class Neighborhood(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    borough = models.ForeignKey(Borough)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

In my forms.py file, I have a simple form being rendered with the options:

```
class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    neighborhood = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(required=False, queryset=Neighborhood.objects.all(), widget=CheckboxSelectMultiple())
```

This is fine and lists out all the options in my Neighborhood model. It looks something like this:

- Lower East Side
- Times Square
- East Village
- West Village
- ...etc

  However, I would like to list the parent category of the neighborhood, in this case the borough.  The desired look would be like this:
- Brooklyn

  - Williamsburg
  - DUMBO
  - ...
- Manhattan

  - Lower East Side
  - Times Square
  - West Village
  - East Village
- Queens

  - ...

I've tried to call the two different objects and combine them into a custom list, however I'm not able to pass that through the queryset as it gave me an AttributeError for not having 'all' available.

Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The best way, I think, is to write custom form widget for it.

Simple (and not bad too) way is to output `<select>` tag in template manually. [regroup](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup) filter will do all the job.

Comment: Thanks DrTyrsa! I initially started out on the custom widget route, but thought there had to be an easier way.  I would have simply outputted the <select> tags manually, but the items should be dynamic and will change when admins change choice selections.  I will try to write my own custom widget for this - thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

For future people going down the same path:

I found [this link](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2019/01/02/how-to-implement-grouped-model-choice-field.html) where it explains how to do it by creating a custom ModelChoiceIterator (the class responsible for making the choices tuple for choice fields) and making it include the parent category.

P.S. The author creates a new ModelChoiceField that uses the new iterator, but I believe you can now simply set a custom iterator using the iterator argument of both ModelChoiceField and ModelMultipleChoiceField ([link to docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField.iterator))